# Finding similar words in text with regex and getting index of them

Tags: python, regex

Here is the data I have.

```
t = 'Billy and Willy and Billy and someone'
words = ['Billy', 'Willy', 'Billy']
```

I planned to find the words in order. First I find Billy, then I shorten the line until the end of the word Billy.

for example:

```
new_t = ' and Willy and Billy and someone'
```

And then I planned to find Willy and etc.

So here what I have written:

```
t = 'Billy and Willy and Billy and someone'
words = ['Billy', 'Willy', 'Billy']
indexes = []
j = 0
for i in words:
    l = re.search(i, t[j:]).span()
    indexes.append(l)
    j = l[1]
```

I know I did wrong, but can you help me to get result like this:

```
Billy = (0,5)
Willy = (10,15)
Billy = (20,25)
```

Comment: It would help readers if you stated the problem fully at the outset, before discussing the approach you considered. Where you say "I planned to find the words in order." it's not clear if the words in `words` are required to appear in the string in the order they appear in `words`.  What if the string were `'Billy and Willy'`, `'Billy and Billy and Willy'` or `'Billy and Willy and Billy and Willy'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find exact substrings, you don't need `re`. You can instead use `str.index`:

```py
t = 'Billy and Willy and Billy and someone'
words = ['Billy', 'Willy', 'Billy']

indexes = []
current_pos = 0
for word in words:
    ind = t.index(word, current_pos)
    indexes.append((ind, ind + len(word)))
    current_pos = ind + 1

print(indexes) # [(0, 5), (10, 15), (20, 25)]
for w, i in zip(words, indexes):
    print(w, '=', i)
# Billy = (0, 5)
# Willy = (10, 15)
# Billy = (20, 25)
```

The second parameter of `index` is the starting position of the search, so you only need to update the starting position (`current_pos`) once a search is done.

Or with walrus operator (python 3.8+), you can shorten the second paragraph into

```py
b = 0
indexes = [(a := t.index(w, b), b := a + len(w)) for w in words]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re`:

```
import re

t = 'Billy and Willy and Billy and someone'
words = 'Billy', 'Willy'

for match in re.finditer('|'.join(words), t):
    print(f"{match[0]} = {match.span()}")
```

---

```
Billy = (0, 5)
Willy = (10, 15)
Billy = (20, 25)
```